# Php connection with SQL Server 2012

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to make a connection to sql server 2012 with php, but always shows

**Erro: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An invalid keyword 'Databases' was specified in the DSN string.**

Can someone help me with this?
 here is the code that i use to make the connection

```
<?php
session_start();

$servername = 'SERVERNAME';
$username = 'sa';
$password = '12345678';
$dbname = 'DBNAME';
//connection
try {

$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servername;database=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY , true);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Erro: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn=null;

?>
```

Comment: this is the right way. the problem was an program

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used SQL server 2012 but try changing

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servername;database=$dbname", $username, $password);
```

To

```
$conn = new PDO("mssql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
```